# Plotting ACF repeater on a Google Map

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

Im building out a wordpress site that plots custom data on a google map using Advanced Custom Fields Pro but can't get it to generate the map using the custom page I have created.

I have created a Google Map Picker with ACF which I have assigned to a post category type ID 4. This is functioning as expected and I can pick the location for each post

In my custom template for wordpress site I have entered the below code to call any location information from the Category in question in this case its ID is 4

This Section pulls and displays the location as expected on the page ( I will be hiding it in the final build)

```
<?php
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=4&posts_per_page=10' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>

  <?php the_field('location'); ?>


<?php endwhile; ?>
 </div>
```

However the map just pulls the first blog an does not display the other 
Below is the code im using to call the location and pass it into the map

```
<?php if( have_rows('sdg_location') ): ?>
    <div class="acf-map">
        <?php while ( have_rows('sdg_location') ) : the_row(); 

            $location = get_field('location');

            ?>
            <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" 
    data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>">

            </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can anyone advise of a better method of doing this? Is there a way to pass the location from the categories directly into the map call?

Below is a screenshot of whats happening can anyone advise?

Thanks a million for your help in advance 
[Screenshot of map and locations loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i0wD.png)

Comment: think I cracked it see here for same issue: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/display-maps-on-front-end/

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using this code

```
 <? $map_posts = get_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'cat' => '4'));
if( $map_posts ): ?>
<div class="acf-map">
    <?php foreach( $map_posts as $map_post ) : 

        $location = get_field('location', $map_post->ID);

        ?>
        <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>">

        </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```